# NativeScript plugin: unable to create instance of MQMapView (MapQuest)

Tags: angular, nativescript, mapquest

I am creating a custom plugin for Mapquest. But got stuck with instance for MQMapView.

I tried to create instance using

approach 1

```
console.log("map init  " + MQMapView.new );
let mapview = MQMapView.new();
console.log("map object" + mapview);
```

Logs:

CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-mapquestplugin/mapquestplugin.js:7:20: map init  function new() {
[native code]
}

After this nothing happens or gets printed in the log.

approach 2

```
let map = MQMapView.alloc();
console.log("map alloc" + map)
console.log("map init  " + map.init );
let mapView =  map.init();
console.log("map object" + mapView);
```

logs:

CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-mapquestplugin/mapquestplugin.js:8:20: map alloc
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-mapquestplugin/mapquestplugin.js:9:20: map init  function init() {
[native code]
}

Same for this approach nothing happens.
even I tried with initWithFrameStyleURL() no use.

gitlink: https://github.com/venkatpruthvi/mapquestplugin.git